# Conversion to timestamp from two columns

Tags: sql, timestamp, netezza

I need to convert two columns into timestamp value.

```
SELECT  
TO_TIMESTAMP(PRGM_START_DAY_KEY,PRGM_START_TM_KEY)
FROM DEV_AM_2..AM_TV_PROGRAM_INSTANCE_DIM
```

The sample values are below.

```
(Input) 20110908 223000  ---------> (Output) 2011-09-08 22:30:00
20110908 73000
```

PRGM_START_DAY_KEY - INTEGER
PRGM_START_TM_KEY - INTEGER

Comment: MySql, SQL Server, Oracle, what are you using?

Comment: Tell us more about the source data. What data types? Also, what database system? Timestamp handling varies a great deal between the different systems.

Comment: I am using Netezza..Both the columns are strings.

Comment: Don't store date/time types as anything other than a date or a time, and store them as a timestamp if they logically belong together.  At least this data sorts/indexes properly, compared to some formats (*USA - MM/DD/YYYY).  What does your documentation say about accepted formats for string input - most RDBMSs I'm aware of will accept strings as input for date/time values, provided they are formatted recognizably (which usually _includes_ seperators, like `/`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution to my above question.

```
SELECT
TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR(TO_DATE(PRGM_START_DAY_KEY,'YYYYMMDD'),1,10)||' '|| CAST(LPAD(PRGM_START_TM_KEY,6,0) AS TIME),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
FROM DEV_AM_2..AM_TV_PROGRAM_INSTANCE_DIM;
```

Regards,
Venk

Comment: Actually I don't have privilege to mark it as answer.That was the reason I couldn't mark it.